# Angular innerHTML limitation in dynamic component injection

Tags: angular, innerhtml, code-injection

I have this type of safe HTML string that comes from the server, it is a preview that I want to inject into an Angular 6.0 application.
The number of sections and sub-section is varying.

```html
<div id="s1" class="section">
 <div class="section-content">
  start of content
  <div id="ss1" class="sub-section">
   content of sub-section
  </div>
  end of content
 </div>
</div>
```

Basically I know how to use the innerHTML attribute to do this. The problem is that I have to make this preview "reacting" like an Angular component.
So I thought about dynamic component injection, a component for the section and a component for the sub-section. For the sub-section rendering is easily done with a
innerHTML attribute. But I do not know how to render the section because inside "start of content" a tag can be opened and close only in "end of content" this
exclude the use of the innerHTML attribute for rendering the section that must be included in a parent tag.

Does any one can help me on this subject ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: First of all leave the idea of having innerHTML for dynamic content specially when the you have Angular Component in it. Here is the example of dynamic creation of component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamically-creating-components-mjnfns

Comment: Thanks for your attention and this good sample with output event strategy in dynamic component injection. My goal is to inject dynamically unknown components, With other answer, i realise that i had to compile them on th fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem will be solved if you make a on-the-fly component that will be helpful with your case I thought

Check the last section of this article which talks in depth about it with code example: 
https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36

Comment: Your answer saved my life ! Thanks again. I just would like to show you this arcticle that's going deeper in the technique (with AOT and JIT problematic):
https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e